# Do the IBuffer objects produced by the methods in Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer have security features?

Tags: c#, c++, security, cryptography, uwp

The Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer class contains static methods for converting between strings and an IBuffer-implementing object which can be used by the cryptography functions. Do these objects have special security measures internally, such as preventing paging to disk, encrypting at rest, and/or erasing when the object is freed? If not, is there an alternative?

For the alternatives, C#/.Net for Windows Universal Apps is preferred; C++/CX if necessary.

EDIT: Asking the second part of the question here: [Do the IBuffer objects produced by the methods in Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer have security features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204614/do-the-ibuffer-objects-produced-by-the-methods-in-windows-security-cryptography)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer is only responsible for implementing data management. For other security measures you need to implement yourself.

For example:

1) You may start a background task for encrypting at rest;

2) As about paging to disk, I don't see a way to do so. This is because Metro style apps, different from desktop apps, are usually suspended whenever they are no longer in the foreground. When they’re suspended, they aren’t touching ANY of their memory.

3) As about this function, "erasing when the object is freed", could you explain more about what kind of things you need to erasing?

Comment: I was assuming that the underlying library might be able to do things that I couldn't do on my own.

Comment: As an example: Passwords, private keys. You wouldn't want to leave those in the clear in memory for longer than you need it.

Comment: 1) If you want forward secrecy, you need to erase ephemeral keys when you no longer need them. Sometimes you also want to erase plaintext data. 2) At least in a desktop application, you can mark pages to be not eligible for swapping. This is often done to keys, since erasing data on disk can't be done reliably.

Comment: If you use those algorithm providers and key providers of  Windows.Security.Cryptography, the Windows.Security.Cryptography will make sure the internal process data is encrypted. However, for the input and output variables (mostly for storing input plaintext and output key), you need to maintain yourself.

Comment: Well, that would be fine in general. However, as far as I know, there is no way to write to the IBuffer in C#, which means there is no way for a program to undertake these security measures. Which either means the library needs to take responsibility, or the interfaces need to be provided to allow the developer to take responsibility.

Comment: Yes you can do that - I added an answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33441644/4184842)